# FileManager IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm beginer with swift/Xcode. I've put a csv file in my simulator and also in my Iphone by airdrop in Document. I try to find it and i've always : FILE NOT AVAILABLE
I've look at my Iphone the file is in Document
Have you an idea to fix this problem?
Is there a solution to find it anywhere in my Iphone or simulator unless I know the path?
Thank you very much
Best regards

```
***let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("players.csv") {
    let filePath = pathComponent.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
    } else {
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
    }
} else {
    print("FILE PATH NOT AVAILABLE")
}***
```

Comment: `.documentDirectory` is the `Documents` directory of **your** app. If you want to access user's files you'll need to use something like [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller), but it may be a more advanced topic if you're a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

This should explain how to get the file and use it

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/working-with-files-and-folders-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact the file "players.csv" was not in documentDirectory but in Cloud drive of my Iphone. this is the reason I don't found that with filemanager. But i don't know if it is possible to find it with fileManager by searching it in Cloud drive.